# How to export highlighted text in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

Highlighted text in Keynote (using `Insert > Highlight`) is not visible when presenting, printing or exporting to other formats, such as PDF. How can this visual cue be preserved?

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted text is, presumably on purpose by Apple, not shown anywhere but in the authoring interface. To get an equivalent effect that is shown elsewhere, and can be exported, use `Format > Text > Style > Font > Cogwheel icon for More text options panel > Text background`